# Array.prototype.join() doesn't work in react useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `join()`, but it just doesn't work, the console send a warning message saying `Uncaught TypeError: calcNumbers.join is not a function`; see the code below.

```
  import { useState } from "react";

  const [calcNumbers, setCalcNumbers] = useState(['1', '2', '3','4'])

  setCalcNumbers(calcNumbers.join(''))
```

Comment: It works fine on the first render.  But have you looked up what `Array.prototype.join()` *returns*?  It returns a *string*.  Once you set `calcNumbers` to a string, what do you expect `calcNumbers.join('')` to do and why?  Taking a step back... Why are you explicitly setting state to one value and then *immediately* setting it to another value?  Why not just initialize it as the value you want?

Comment: you're setting an array of strings to a string, so how array's method will work on string type? Please spend more time learning the basics of JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for first time because you have array , after join method it changed to string , string type has not join('') method.